# JS event inside table won't fire

Tags: javascript, button, click, addeventlistener

When creating a table with JS and having a button inside that table, with an eventListener on that button, the event just won't be triggered when clicking the button. I am calling this function inside a forEach-Loop to dynamically build my table, and apply the event-Listener for each button.

Here's my original code:

```
static createList(item) {
    let table = document.getElementById("rows")
    let row = table.insertRow();
    let cell_1 = row.insertCell();
    cell_1.innerHTML = item.id_recipient_sms;
    let cell_2 = row.insertCell();
    cell_2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" placeholder="' + item.phone_number + '" id="smsRecipient' + item.id_recipient_sms + '">';

    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = 'button';
    inputElement.id = item.id_recipient_sms;
    inputElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(item.id_recipient_sms)
    });

    let cell_3 = row.insertCell();
    cell_3.appendChild(inputElement);
}
```

Which is not working in my program. I created a code snippet, which is working, though.
Can it have sth to do with the addEventListener within the loop?
I still can't find the misstake in my original code.

```js
let table = document.getElementById("rows")
                            let row = table.insertRow();
                            let cell_1 = row.insertCell();
                            cell_1.innerHTML = "cell1";

                            let cell_2 = row.insertCell();
                            cell_2.innerHTML = "cell2";

                            var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
                            inputElement.type = 'button';
                            inputElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                alert("It Works here");
                            });

                            let cell_3 = row.insertCell();
                            cell_3.appendChild(inputElement);
```

```html
<table id="rows">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, your code works right in here.

[image]

Comment: I know that. Still, it isn't working in my original code.

Comment: Did u use this `static foo(){}` inside class ?

Comment: Yeah, i thought it may have sth. to do with that, maybe..?

Comment: Yeah, you can use this for to do smth, but syntax looks correct. I don't what to say, but if you want you can check this documentation. maybe you can find anything for correction :) https://javascript.info/class

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the function in the code. That is why it doesn't work. Instead inside the script tag or in the external js file, add the code without function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="rows">
    </table>
  </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 let table = document.getElementById("rows")
                             let row = table.insertRow();
                             let cell_1 = row.insertCell();
                             cell_1.innerHTML = "cell1";

                             let cell_2 = row.insertCell();
                             cell_2.innerHTML = "cell2";

                             var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
                             inputElement.type = 'button';
                             inputElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                 alert("It Works here");
                             });

                             let cell_3 = row.insertCell();
                             cell_3.appendChild(inputElement);

 </script>
</html>
```

This worked?

Comment: I am calling the function...the function builds the html-table but the event-listener is just not applied. (There is no "ev" marker in firefox inspector)